# Unable to do find using variable in query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I was working on a project on windows on NodeJS.

I used the following code for checking login credentials. It was working fine till I changed to **ubuntu 16.04** .

I set up my environment and now the variables are not being treated as strings.

It's returning empty set from the DB. If I do it like this `user_name:"some user name",password:"some password"`, it's working fine.

Please help. I am stuck bad :-( sorry if its a noob type mistake :-)

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var N1 = req.body.N1;
    var N2 = req.body.N2;
    console.log(N1+N2);//Getting passed successfully
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            console.log("into connectivity error");
        }
        console.log(N1);
        db.collection('col.login').find({user_name:N1,pass:N2}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            resultArray=result;
            try{
                req.session.userId = result[0]._id;
                req.session.userType = result[0].type;
                req.session.userComp = result[0].comp_id;
                req.session.cat = -1;
                if(result[0].type=="root") {
                    res.redirect('/New_Company');
                }
```

database structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
    "user_name" : "xxxxxxx",
    "pass" : "xxxxx",
    "type" : "root",
    "email" : "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "comp_name" : "NULL",
    "default_page" : "main",
    "name" : "xxxxx",
    "comp_id" : "NULL"
}
```

Comment: What value you are getting for `console.log(N1);` ?

Comment: i checked both N1 and N2 they are what i posted from the login page

Comment: Can you share your db structure?

Comment: sure give me a moment

Comment: Not sure why it is not working. Can you try doing `toString()` for `N2 and N1` and see if it is working?

Comment: sure give me another moment.

Comment: var N1 = toString(req.body.N1);  var N2 = toString(req.body.N2); i used this still no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113996/discussion-between-user287332-and-titi23).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following way :-

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
var N1 = (req.body.N1).toString();//Do toString()
var N2 = (req.body.N2).toString();
console.log(N1+N2);//Getting passed successfully
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
        console.log("into connectivity error");
    }
    console.log(N1);
    db.collection('col.login').find({user_name:N1,pass:N2}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        resultArray=result;
        try{
            req.session.userId = result[0]._id;
            req.session.userType = result[0].type;
            req.session.userComp = result[0].comp_id;
            req.session.cat = -1;
            if(result[0].type=="root") {
                res.redirect('/New_Company');
            }
      });
```

Refer [toString](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_string.asp) for more info on `toString()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.